# How do I port StrongDelegate ObjC code to C# MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin.ios, multipeer-connectivity, objective-c-2.0

I'm [porting](https://github.com/makerofthings7/Xamarin-WiTap-MultiPeer) the [Official Apple Multipeer WiTap sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/WiTap/Introduction/Intro.html) to Xamarin and C#, however I'm not sure how to port this method within TapViewController.

It contains all the things I'm not sure how to port... namely

1. A delegate that is expressed only in code, and has no strong delegate in the Xamarin framework. (this is probably easy, just a concept I'm missing)
2. What the heck is the `id` here, and how do I declare/use it?
3. How do I declare `self.delegate;`

code:

```
- (IBAction)closeButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    id <TapViewControllerDelegate>  strongDelegate;

    #pragma unused(sender)
    strongDelegate = self.delegate;
    if ([strongDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tapViewControllerDidClose:)]) {
        [strongDelegate tapViewControllerDidClose:self];
    }
}
```

Here is a [link to my code](https://github.com/makerofthings7/Xamarin-WiTap-MultiPeer), where the port [is in progress](https://github.com/makerofthings7/Xamarin-WiTap-MultiPeer)

Comment: That's objective-c, not swift

Answer (score 1):

Are you attempting to port Objective-C code to C# without knowing the former?

- `id` is Obj-C's "any object", while `id<protocolName>` is any object which implements the specified protocol. An Obj-C "delegate" is just an object which implements a given protocol, it is the way it is used that makes it a delegate. Objc-C protocols and C# interfaces are matching concepts. So `strongDelegate` is a variable whose type is a C# interface (which you've presumably translated from the Obj-C protocol).
- Declaring `self.delegate`: it's an Objc-C property reference with the same (or compatible) type as `strongDelegate`. C# has properties.
- The `if` test in Obj-C is determine whether the referenced object implements the specified method and if so invokes it. Obj-C protocols allow optional methods, i.e. methods objects implementing the protocol need not implement. C# interfaces have no direct equivalent. In your translation of the Obj-C protocol to a C# interface you either made all optional methods non-optional, or you did something else. Translate the `if` to match whatever you did.

HTH